# Get data from payload when remote push notification arrive while my app is in background or closed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to capture data from payload when recive a remote push notification, on IOS 9 i did this using the func:
didReceiveRemoteNotification
On IOS 10 using swift 3.0 i've implemented this 2 functions.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
print("\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
{
print("User Info = ",response.notification.request.content.userInfo)

completionHandler()
}
```

the second fuction only executes when the user touch the push

i need capture data when a push notification arrives while my app is in background or even closed.

Regards. 
greetings

Answer (score 2):

When a push notification is received and your app isn't running, you need to implement your notification logic in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   // Called when a notification is tapped and the app wasn't running, not in foreground neither in background. 
   if let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject]{
        // your logic here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // Capture payload here something like:
    let appState = userInfo["appState"] as? String
    print(appState!)

    // Do something for every state
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active){
        print("Active")

    }else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background){
        print("Background")


    }else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive){
        print("Inactive")

    }

    completionHandler(.noData)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with the didReceiveRemoteNotification function in iOS10:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

                   print(userInfo)

             }
```

Comment: Hi, i did it, and i was able to capture data from push notification in background sendind on aps content-available=1. but when app is closed it seems that never executes.

Comment: Hey @Christian Gonzalez if user close or terminate app by own then we can't do anything like this.